# Android videoView over 3G connection

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am working on a small project that uses videoView to display a .3GP video file inside the application. My code works in the emulator fine but on the physical device (Samsung Nexus S) it only works over WiFi and times out on 3G. Below is the code I'm using

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);


Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras();
String path = info.getString("link");

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

videoView.setVideoPath(path);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.requestFocus();

videoView.start();

mediaController.show();
```

XML file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/videoView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

And here's the logcat for WiFi and 3G

Over 3G (doesn't work)

```
D/MediaPlayer( 6984): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
I/AwesomePlayer(   81): setDataSource_l('http://url.com/ski/famous.
3gp')
V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(   81): connect on behalf of uid 10111
I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(   81): connect to http://url.com/ski/famo
us.3gp @0
I/ActivityManager(  150): Displayed com.madarasan.SkiDroid/.VideoViewActivity: +
82ms
I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(   81): OnReadCompleted, read failed, status 4
E/NuCachedSource2(   81): source returned error -1004, 10 retries left
D/ConnectivityService(  150): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=100,
published condition=0
```

Over WiFi (works)

```
D/MediaPlayer( 6984): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
I/AwesomePlayer(   81): setDataSource_l('http://url.com/ski/famous.
3gp')
V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(   81): connect on behalf of uid 10111
I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(   81): connect to http://url.com/ski/famo
us.3gp @0
I/ActivityManager(  150): Displayed com.madarasan.SkiDroid/.VideoViewActivity: +
128ms
I/OMXCodec(   81): [OMX.SEC.MPEG4.Decoder] video dimensions are 320 x 240
```

Is there any reason videoView would not work over 3G? Am I using it wrong? Is there a better/simpler way to show video in Android? I don't mind using other file types 3GP was just an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried over more wifi connections or even other 3G connection (other operator), could be a proxy over you 3G network..

Related:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27017072

Seems some network problems from your company.